# Could not resolve all dependencies for ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc:_debugPublishCopy'. > com.android.support:support-annotations

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, twilio

Dependency problem when compiling a react-native app on the Android platform.
Error is referencing this module I'm using: https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc but I'm not sure it's specific to it, seems to be a SDK-related issue ?

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Try compiling the app, either debug or release

#### Expected behaviour

App should compile succesfully

#### Actual behaviour

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc:_debugPublishCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0.
  >          Searched in the following locations:
  >              file:/Users/antoine/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.1.0/support-annotations-26.1.0.pom
  >              file:/Users/antoine/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.1.0/support-annotations-26.1.0.jar
  >              file:/Users/antoine/R/medwayapp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.1.0/support-annotations-26.1.0.jar
  >          Required by:
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0.
  >          Searched in the following locations:
  >              file:/Users/antoine/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.1.0/support-annotations-26.1.0.pom
  >              file:/Users/antoine/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.1.0/support-annotations-26.1.0.jar
  >              file:/Users/antoine/R/medwayapp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.1.0/support-annotations-26.1.0.jar
  >          Required by:
  >              project :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc > com.twilio:video-android:1.3.8
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED`

#### Environment

- **Node.js version**: v8.4.0
- **React Native version**: 0.42.0
- **React Native platform + platform version**: Android 7

#### react-native-twilio-video-webrtc

**Version**: master

#### build.gradle lines specific to this issue

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    dexOptions {
      jumboMode true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Gradle build tools: 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Fixed ! Turned out my modules now had a dependency to `com.android.support:support-annotations` and that none of the repositories I was fetching packages from had it. I had to add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to my top-level `build.gradle` repositories to make it work.